# How to compare two rows and when they are different then create another dataframe to copy these two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Check column ['esn'] from df1. When any different found between two rows, produce another dataframe, df2. df2 only contains the before change and after change information

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2014,1],[2015,1],[2016,1],[2017,2],[2018,2]],columns=['year','esn'])
>>> df1
   year  esn
0  2014    1
1  2015    1
2  2016    1
3  2017    2
4  2018    2
>>> df2 # new dataframe intended to create
   year  esn
0  2016    1
1  2017    2
```

can't produce the above result in df2. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolena mask by compare shifted values by `ne` for not equal and replace first missing value by `backfill`, similar compare shifted with `-1` with forward filling missing values - chain by `|` for `bitwise OR` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df1['esn'].ne(df1['esn'].shift().bfill()) | df1['esn'].ne(df1['esn'].shift(-1).ffill())

df2 = df1[mask]
print (df2)
   year  esn
2  2016    1
3  2017    2
```